# How to compile a file which uses libtiff functions in C++ in windows?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, libtiff

I downloaded the required files from [GNUWin32 LibTiff page](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tiff.htm).
I didn't install it but used the lib and include to run my code. I want to make my code portable.

---

Here is my basic C++ program taken from LibTiff documentation.

File: abcd.cpp

```
#include <tiffio.h>

int main()
{
    TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen("foo.tif","r");
    TIFFClose(tif);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create an executable `abcd.exe`.

My folder structure:

```
MyProject
|
|tifflib
    |
    |include
    |bin
    |lib
    |manifest
|abcd.cpp
```

These are the commands I ran:

```
g++ -c -Itifflib\include -o abcd.o abcd.cpp

g++ -Ltifflib\lib -o abcd.exe abcd.o -ltiff
```

---

I get the following error:

```
skipping incompatible tifflib\lib\libtiff.a when searching for -ltiff
skipping incompatible tifflib\lib\libtiff.dll.a when searching for -ltiff
cannot find -ltiff
```

Comment: The error says the files you downloaded are incompatible. You might have mixed up 32 / 64 bit?

Comment: How do you mean, I mixed up? That my library is 32 bit and OS is 64 bit?

Comment: But, doesn't windows support both 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: I recommend a package manager like [conan](https://conan.io/) with a build tool like [cmake](https://cmake.org/). It will handle the dependencies.

Comment: I'm using 64bit Windows 8

Comment: I'll try out conan but my workstation doesn't have access to internet

Comment: You have to match the .a files with your compiler's version + bits.

Comment: @TarunMaganti There's an option in g++ to compile for 32 bit `-m32` add it to both your commands and see what happens.

Comment: @nada I don't know what that means..

Comment: @TarunMaganti glad to help

Comment: @TarunMaganti If you want 64 bit I'd try and find libtiff somewhere more modern than gnuwin32, that stuff is really ancient

Comment: @john That would mean, I'd have to recompile it for myself right?